# Compute 3D gradient directions in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gradient

I have a `160x120` OpenCV Mat in which I have stored a `Vec3F` vector at each position. The `Vec3f` holds `(x, y, z)` information for a specific pixel that has been computed through 3D reconstruction using a intensity image and a corresponding depthmap.
So I basically map from a `Mat` holding a greyscale value at each pixel to a `Mat` holding 3D position information at each pixel.

Then I tried to compute the gradients for each pixel in that `Mat` object. I therefore have implemented this code in C++/OpenCV:

```
for(int x = 0; x < mat.rows; ++x){
    for(int y = 0; y < mat.cols; ++y){
        float Gx = (mat.at<Vec3f>(x+1, y)[0] - mat.at<Vec3f>(x-1, y)[0]) / 2.0;
        float Gy = (depth.at<Vec3f>(x, y+1)[1] - depth.at<Vec3f>(x, y-1)[1]) / 2.0;

        Vec3f d = (Gx, Gy, 1.0);
        Vec3f n = normalize(d);
        allGradients.push_back(n);
    }
}

// mat.at<Vec3f>(x, y)[0] -> Get the Vec3F vector at the current x-, y- 
// position in the Mat and access its first element (which is the points x-value).
```

So I computed the gradient directions `Gx` and `Gy` with the method of finite difference approximation.

What I don't understand is how to compute the gradient in the z-direction. I do have the z-information for every pixel stored in the `Vec3f` along with the x-, and y-information but the step of finite difference approximation wont be possible, as the data is stored in a `2D Mat`, right?

So I cannot simply access the pixel in front and behind he current one by doing something similar like this:

```
 float Gz = (mat.at<Vec3f>(x, y, z+1)[2] - mat.at<Vec3f>(x, y, z-1)[2]) / 2.0;
```

as in a `Mat` I have not z-value, right? If so, how can I then compute the gradient in the z-direction? Would I need to store my information in a `3D array`? Or is the whole approach incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: not sure whether your 2D gradient makes sense. I know 3D gradients from 3D volumetric data like density grids like from CT scans or dense 3D reconstruction (like kinect fusion). However you can transform your sparse points representation to a 3D grid, if you want to. Probably to answer the question you should tell what you want to do with the gradient information. Maybe it is enough to approximate the 2D surface plane in that object/pixel position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you have is a 3-dimensional object which you have somehow coerced into a 2D matrix. If you truly have a 3D volumetric object, you can use the following `Opencv Mat` constructor

```
Mat::Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type)
```

See the documentation here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat

This constructor allows you to create n-dimensional `Mat` objects. Example:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(3, {100, 100, 10}, CV_32SC1)
```

If your input is a 2-dimensional spatial object with some 3-dimensional field attached at every pixel, then of course, the `spatial gradient` along the z-direction is 0 but I am guessing your input is a full volumetric object?